# Передать видео с ip камеры в vk.com

Tags: linux, потоки-данных, видео, ffmpeg

ffmpeg version 4.1.4 работает такой стрим работает

```
ffmpeg -an -i "rtsp://192.168.116.216/user=admin_password=tlJwpbo6_channel=1_stream=0.sdp" -map 0  -f flv -vcodec copy -s 1920x1080 -r 12  -acodec aac "rtmp://stream3.vkuserlive.com:443/vlive.629625.XXXX/XXXX"
```

Но на Openwrt ffmpeg version 3.2.12 и такой поток не запустился.

```
    [rtsp @ 0x77465890] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://192.168.116.216/user=admin_password=tlJwpbo6_channel=1_stream=0.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP Session
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
[aac @ 0xf1c530] Too many bits 8832.000000 > 6144 per frame requested, clamping to max
[flv @ 0xf19cd0] dimensions not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argumentStream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw (native) -> aac (native))
    Last message repeated 1 times
[aac @ 0xf1c530] Qavg: nan
```

С какими параметрами можно запуститься на версии 3?

ffmpeg собран с параметрами --disable-parser=h264... Как указать вручную параметры потока?

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 12 fps, 12 tbr, 90k tbn, 24 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
```

Comment: Попробуйте `-flags +global_header` дописать где-нибудь после acodec

Comment: не заметил ошибку выше. добавил в вопрос.

Comment: А если `-rtsp_transport tcp` в начале дописать? Впрочем, я с --disable-parser=h264 никогда не работал...

Comment: пробовал, не обнаруживает формат пикселя и размеры